# Error 1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, database, replace, set, mysql-error-1064

I want run this query but get an error:

> Error 1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `ads` SET `aDesc` = replace(aDesc, 'amp;', '')' at line 3

My query is:

```
UPDATE `ads`
SET `aName` = replace(aName, 'amp;', '')
UPDATE `ads`
SET `aDesc` = replace(aDesc, 'amp;', '');
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you please format your question and queries properly?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks like two queries without a separating delimiter.

The more efficient option is to do both changes in one query:

```
UPDATE ads
SET aName = replace(aName, 'amp;', ''),
    aDesc = replace(aDesc, 'amp;', '');
```

but if you must run two queries:

```
UPDATE ads SET aName = replace(aName, 'amp;', '');
UPDATE ads SET aDesc = replace(aDesc, 'amp;', '');
```